# Typescript narrow a type from a given interface

Tags: typescript

In the project I am working on we use GraphQL with the

```
 __typename: "Specific" | "Normal"
```

property. In this particular request I can only get an array of items with the `__typename` of `"Specific"`.
How do I tell Typescript that I want exactly that interface but I am sure that `__typename` can only have that one value.

Comment: `Type assertion` should work. Do you have an example? I could write the answer then.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. That both helps communicate the problem clearly, and makes it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a query that you know will only return `__typename: "Specific"` items and you want to type them accordingly without repeating all of the other aspects of the interface with that property.

To do that, you can define a new interface like this:

```typescript
type NarrowedInterface = OriginalInterface & {
  __typename: "Specific";
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJWAc1HANgSXGniWQG8AoZZOALmQGcwMRMBuK5AI3pAFcAtl2gdqAfTFgAngAcIIOAIj0ARAGU5CYDGAIVyAD7IVAOQD2UAXhUcAvhQrS5yE3ChQzAdwgATQpFhEFABeNAxsBQIiQNIAMnJOCSd5RWVjDQgtHT07DgofTNw3FFwIMGQAD3pXdy9ff2IgjgqAOiTZFKU2ZAB6HuQAFQ7kYAZ0zW1dFSA)

Comment: Wouldn't `var as "Specific"` yield the same result? :) Although a bit hardcoded here but with enums this could be solved.

Comment: @GytisTG - It depends on what you're trying to do. In this case I assumed the OP wanted a type to use for the query, e.g. `const items: NarrowedInterface[] = graphql(/*...*/);` But I could be mistaken.